# Plotting complex graph in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset

```
ids             count
1               2000210
2              -23123
3               100
4               500
5               102300120
...
1 million       123213
```

I want a graph where I have group of `ids` (all unique ids) in the x axis and `count` in y axis and a distribution chart that looks like the following

[image]

How can I achieve this in pandas dataframe in python.

I tried different ways but I am only getting a basic plot and not as complex as the drawing.

What I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000000, 2), columns=["count", "ids"]).cumsum()

df["range"] = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))))

df.plot(x="range", y="count");
```

But the plots dont make any sense. I am also new to plotting in pandas. I searched for a long time for charts like this in the internet and could really use some help with such graphs

Comment: Do you have to use only pandas or you are open to other libraries too?

Comment: Open to other libraries as well.

Comment: Your reproducible example it not a Gaussian, it's thus difficult to generalize. Do you want `df.plot.hist(x="range", y="count")`?

Comment: in your data you have `ids` and `count`, but in your code you also added a `range` column, in your drawing where is the `range`?

Comment: If you wont find suitable solution, Ill be back in like 10 hours and I'll help you with the seaborn library

Comment: I have around a million unique ids and plotting for each of them individually didnt make sense. So I want to group them. For example. 1000 ids have XXX count, 60,000 ids have YYY count etc... Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it does, but what you did on your rage means that every row will have the length of the DataFrame until that point, which means if you have 1m points you'll have 1m range points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood from your question and comments here is what you can do:

#### 1) Import the libraries and set the default theme:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme()
```

#### 2) Create your dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000000, 2), columns=["count", "ids"]).cumsum()
df["range"] = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))))
```

#### 3) Plot your data

##### 3.1) Simple take using only the `seaborn` library:

```py
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="count", weights="range")
```

##### Output:

[image: seaborn_only_solution]

##### 3.2) More complex take using `seaborn` and `matplotlib` libraries:

```py
sns.histplot(x=df["count"], weights=df["range"], discrete=True,
             color='darkblue', edgecolor='black',
             kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 2}, line_kws={'linewidth': 4})
plt.ylabel("range")
plt.show()
```

##### Output:

[image: seaborn_matplotlib_solution]

> Personal note: please make sure to check all the solutions, if they
> are not enough comment and we will work together in order to find you
> a solution

Answer (score 0):

From a distribution plot of `ids` you can use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(seed=123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000000), columns=["ids"])
df['ids'].plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]